# When i .pb file transfer to .tflite i get an error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bazel

i train a model in python with keras. I save model as .h5 file and after than i use a script for .h5 file to .pb file. You can see my script:

```python
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K
import os.path as osp
import os
import tensorflow as tf

model = load_model("/media/hsmnzaydn/8AD030E8D030DBDF/Projects/Machine Learning/Basic Keras/CancerDetected/modelim.h5")
nb_classes = 1 # The number of output nodes in the model
prefix_output_node_names_of_final_network = 'output_node'

K.set_learning_phase(0)

pred = [None]*nb_classes
pred_node_names = [None]*nb_classes
for i in range(nb_classes):
    pred_node_names[i] = prefix_output_node_names_of_final_network+str(i)
    pred[i] = tf.identity(model.output[i], name=pred_node_names[i])
print('output nodes names are: ', pred_node_names)

sess = K.get_session()
output_fld = 'tensorflow_model/'
if not os.path.isdir(output_fld):
    os.mkdir(output_fld)
output_graph_name = "./" + '.pb'
output_graph_suffix = '_inference'

constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), pred_node_names)
graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, output_fld, output_graph_name, as_text=False)
print('saved the constant graph (ready for inference) at: ', osp.join(output_fld, output_graph_name))
```

And i move .pb file in tensorflow root file.I try bazel command for .pb file to .lite file I use bazel command like this

```python
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco --input_file=modelim.pb --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --output_file=modelim.lite --inference_type=FLOAT --input_type=FLOAT --input_arrays=dense_1_input --output_arrays=output_node0 --input_shapes=1,2
```

but i get this error

```python
2018-03-27 22:23:18.655997: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_cmdline_flags.cc:183] --input_type is deprecated. It was an ambiguous flag that set both --input_data_types and --inference_input_type. If you are trying to complement the input file with information about the type of input arrays, use --input_data_type. If you are trying to control the quantization/dequantization of real-numbers input arrays in the output file, use --inference_input_type.
2018-03-27 22:23:18.656633: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 17 operators, 27 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-03-27 22:23:18.656758: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 17 operators, 27 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-03-27 22:23:18.656837: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:447] Check failed: matmul_repeats * weights_shape.dims(1) == input_overall_size (0 vs. 2)
İptal edildi
```

Do someone know solution?

Comment: I looked at the [source of the error][1], and there's a check to make sure that in the FullyConnected operator, the dimensions are the input are compatible with the dimensions of the weights. Could you manually inspect your graph to see if the dimensions make sense? If that doesn't work, would you be able to share your model (or a version to reproduce the issue)? [1]:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc#L387

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Follow this tutorial to convert keras model to Tflite model https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/rnn#from_keras_model